# Terminology for constructing a vector or matrix of the coefficients of an expression

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have a vector of variables as follows:
$$
X=
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{1} & x_{2}  & \dots  & x_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I also have a function $f$ which returns a linear combination of the values of $X$. For example, it might return:
$$
f(X) = 22.6 x_{1} + 3.2 x_{2} + \dots + 14.4 x_{n}
$$
(The function also takes other parameters to determine those coefficients, which aren't relevant here.)

What I need is the correct mathematical terminology or notation for constructing a vector from $f$ which contains the coefficients of the corresponding values of $X$. For example, if
$$
f(X) = c_{1} x_{1} + c_{2} x_{2} + \dots + c_{n} x_{n}
$$
then I am looking for the correct way to describe how to get $C$ where:
$$
C=\begin{bmatrix}
    c_{1} & c_{2} & \dots & c_{n} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
How can I express this? For example, simple division such as
$$C=\frac{f(X)}{X}$$
obviously isn't right, but is vaguely close to what I'm trying to do. Perhaps there's some operation I don't know about. I don't necessarily expect there to be a way to represent this symbolically, but a sentence would also be fine. For example, "Let C represent the coefficients of something something something." I'm having trouble with the wording and making it any more concise than what I have above.

---

### Edit

This is the best I have so far, based on *@Cat*'s suggestion:

Let $\hat{e}_i$ denote a vector with a 1 in the $i$th coordinate and 0's elsewhere. Then

$$C = \begin{bmatrix} c_{1} & c_{2} & \dots & c_{n}  \end{bmatrix} \text{ where }c_i=f(\hat{e}_i)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at what happens when you plug in the points

$$X_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \end{bmatrix},$$

$$X_2 = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \end{bmatrix},$$
$$
\vdots
$$
$$X_n = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 \end{bmatrix},$$

Comment: I have added an edit with the best language I could come up with, based on this idea. Do you see any better way to phrase it?

Comment: It is exactly right what your wrote, and that is a perfectly fine way to phrase it.

Answer (score 1):

Just define a map $[c_1x_1, ... , c_nx_n] \mapsto [c_1,...,c_n]$ and this will be okay for your purposes by the sounds of it.

Comment: This could definitely work, and is simple, although I'm having trouble writing it concisely. I would prefer to avoid having to write an explanation using both the "f(X) = c1x1 + ... cnxn" line (to define where those ci values came from) as well as this one to define the map.